# Is large language model “perplexity” on an input the total of its perplexity for the smallest parts?

Tags: computational-linguistics, statistical-mt, large-language-models

“Perplexity” is how likely a large language model  scores an output it gives as being the output it should have given. If the model does not produce responses for itself to choose from that it calculates as having a high probability of being a good response, you can say the model is “perplexed”, analogous to the ordinary usage of the word to mean “confused”.

When a model is perplexed, it may or may not provide output that the human deems good quality. I do not know how perplexity actually works. Is the total perplexity of say, a whole sentence, just the result of combining the perplexity (the model’s sense of likelihood) on each word? As a sum, or multiplied?

So, consider a language model in which each word has 6 letters **on average**.

Then would the perplexity of a model on each character by 6 times the perplexity it has on each word? Does perplexity distribute over sizes or does it have more particular or unpredictable dynamics?

I ask because I want to know where the source of an LLMs confusion may come from, to better understand how they make the language decisions they do, ie, on what they are basing their choices on.

https://aclanthology.org/P14-1075.pdf

Comment: How does this relate to linguistics - the scientific study of natural languages?

Comment: So I shall ask it on math. thank you.

Comment: When you do, you might also give your definition of "perplexity".

Comment: Please look up the word perplexity. Surely, you mean complexity?

Comment: @Lambie Perplexity is a standard measurement for probability models including LMs.

Comment: you might search ngram stanford the pdf that google shows you on page 8 discusses perplexity

Comment: “A standard measure for the difficulty of a task is perplexity” https://aclanthology.org/J92-1002.pdf

Comment: Large language models are practically the central object of study in contemporary computational linguistics. They subsume all the previous techniques and succeed them. https://oxfordre.com/linguistics/display/10.1093/acrefore/9780199384655.001.0001/acrefore-9780199384655-e-375?rskey=ey5HYS&result=2

Comment: “Neural models greatly outperform grammar-based models across many tasks in modern computational linguistics. This raises the question of whether linguistic principles, such as the Principle of Compositionality, still have value as modeling tools. We find that while an overly strict interpretation of compositionality makes it hard to achieve broad coverage in semantic parsing tasks, compositionality is still necessary for a model to learn the correct linguistic generalizations from limited data.” - January 2023

https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-linguistics-030521-044439

Comment: We also have a tag for large-language-models now

Comment: @hmltn Normally we'd prefer such large edits not to be made and for the editor to simply ask their own question instead. I won't roll back your edit this time, but please avoid making edits like that in the future.

Comment: I’m open to that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, one cannot rightfully assume that the perplexity of the language model (LM) on character level is 6 times the perplexity of the model on word level. The reason for this is that perplexity and the levels (character or word) it's calculated at are distinct concepts.

Perplexity is a measure of how well a probability model predicts a sample. In the case of a language model, lower perplexity means that the model is better at predicting the next token in the sequence.

When we talk about character level and word level, we're referring to the granularity at which the language model makes its predictions. A character-level LM predicts the next character in the sequence, while a word-level LM predicts the next word.

The perplexity of these models can't be directly compared, because they're essentially solving different tasks. Character-level LMs generally have higher perplexity because there are more possible characters to predict than there are words (when considering the input context length that LMs typically operate with). On the other hand, word-level LMs could also have high perplexity if the vocabulary is large and diverse, or if the language's syntax and semantics are complex.

So, even though the average word length in your language model is 6 letters, this doesn't mean that the character-level perplexity will be 6 times the word-level perplexity. The perplexity at both levels will depend on how well the model is able to predict the next token (character or word) given the previous ones, which is a function of the model's understanding of the language's structure, rather than the average length of the words.

The perplexity of a model for a sequence is usually defined as:

PPL(P) = P(x1,x2,...,xn)^(-1/n)

where:

- P is the probability function defined by your model
- xi are the elements of your sequence
- n is the length of your sequence
- PPL(P) is the perplexity of the model

For character-level and word-level language models, the sequence elements xi would be characters and words, respectively.

Consider a word 'hello' as an example. A language model would calculate the probability of this sequence differently on a character level compared to a word level:

1. Character-Level: P('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o')
2. Word-Level: P('hello')

In character-level model, each character probability depends on the sequence of previous characters. In word-level model, each word's probability depends on the sequence of previous words.

If we were to calculate perplexity for this word for both models, assuming our model's calculated probabilities for the sequence were P_char and P_word respectively, we'd get:

1. Character-Level Perplexity: PPL(P_char) = P_char^(-1/5)  (since 'hello' has 5 characters)
2. Word-Level Perplexity: PPL(P_word) = P_word^(-1/1) = P_word^(-1)  (since 'hello' is 1 word)

While you can see the character-level perplexity involves dividing by 5 (the number of characters), and the word-level perplexity doesn't, this doesn't mean the character-level perplexity is 5 times the word-level perplexity. The probabilities P_char and P_word are typically not equivalent, since they're calculated based on different contexts (preceding characters versus preceding words), making the perplexities different as well.

Hence, the perplexity calculated based on characters does not match the associated perplexity of the whole word. The specific relation between the two perplexities will depend on the details of the language model, the sequence itself, and the larger context in which the sequence appears.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perplexity